# Переопределить метод bindView в SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, наследование

Здравствуйте! Делаю кастомный `SimpleCursorAdapter`, наследуюсь от данного класса, переопределяю `bindView()`, и не понимаю почему в наследнике недоступны поля:

```
protected int[] mFrom;
protected int[] mTo;
```

несмотря на то что они `protected`

```
    /*
 * Copyright (C) 2006 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.widget;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * An easy adapter to map columns from a cursor to TextViews or ImageViews
 * defined in an XML file. You can specify which columns you want, which
 * views you want to display the columns, and the XML file that defines
 * the appearance of these views.
 *
 * Binding occurs in two phases. First, if a
 * {@link android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder} is available,
 * {@link ViewBinder#setViewValue(android.view.View, android.database.Cursor, int)}
 * is invoked. If the returned value is true, binding has occured. If the
 * returned value is false and the view to bind is a TextView,
 * {@link #setViewText(TextView, String)} is invoked. If the returned value
 * is false and the view to bind is an ImageView,
 * {@link #setViewImage(ImageView, String)} is invoked. If no appropriate
 * binding can be found, an {@link IllegalStateException} is thrown.
 *
 * If this adapter is used with filtering, for instance in an
 * {@link android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView}, you can use the
 * {@link android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter} and the
 * {@link android.widget.FilterQueryProvider} interfaces
 * to get control over the filtering process. You can refer to
 * {@link #convertToString(android.database.Cursor)} and
 * {@link #runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence)} for more information.
 */
public class SimpleCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
    /**
     * A list of columns containing the data to bind to the UI.
     * This field should be made private, so it is hidden from the SDK.
     * {@hide}
     */
    protected int[] mFrom;
    /**
     * A list of View ids representing the views to which the data must be bound.
     * This field should be made private, so it is hidden from the SDK.
     * {@hide}
     */
    protected int[] mTo;

    private int mStringConversionColumn = -1;
    private CursorToStringConverter mCursorToStringConverter;
    private ViewBinder mViewBinder;

    String[] mOriginalFrom;

    /**
     * Constructor the enables auto-requery.
     *
     * @deprecated This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries
     * being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor
     * responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors.  As an alternative,
     * use {@link android.app.LoaderManager} with a {@link android.content.CursorLoader}.
     */
    @Deprecated
    public SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c);
        mTo = to;
        mOriginalFrom = from;
        findColumns(c, from);
    }

    /**
     * Standard constructor.
     * 
     * @param context The context where the ListView associated with this
     *            SimpleListItemFactory is running
     * @param layout resource identifier of a layout file that defines the views
     *            for this list item. The layout file should include at least
     *            those named views defined in "to"
     * @param c The database cursor.  Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param from A list of column names representing the data to bind to the UI.  Can be null 
     *            if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param to The views that should display column in the "from" parameter.
     *            These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list
     *            are given the values of the first N columns in the from
     *            parameter.  Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param flags Flags used to determine the behavior of the adapter,
     * as per {@link CursorAdapter#CursorAdapter(Context, Cursor, int)}.
     */
    public SimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
            int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, flags);
        mTo = to;
        mOriginalFrom = from;
        findColumns(c, from);
    }

    /**
     * Binds all of the field names passed into the "to" parameter of the
     * constructor with their corresponding cursor columns as specified in the
     * "from" parameter.
     *
     * Binding occurs in two phases. First, if a
     * {@link android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder} is available,
     * {@link ViewBinder#setViewValue(android.view.View, android.database.Cursor, int)}
     * is invoked. If the returned value is true, binding has occured. If the
     * returned value is false and the view to bind is a TextView,
     * {@link #setViewText(TextView, String)} is invoked. If the returned value is
     * false and the view to bind is an ImageView,
     * {@link #setViewImage(ImageView, String)} is invoked. If no appropriate
     * binding can be found, an {@link IllegalStateException} is thrown.
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if binding cannot occur
     * 
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#bindView(android.view.View,
     *      android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor)
     * @see #getViewBinder()
     * @see #setViewBinder(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder)
     * @see #setViewImage(ImageView, String)
     * @see #setViewText(TextView, String)
     */
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final ViewBinder binder = mViewBinder;
        final int count = mTo.length;
        final int[] from = mFrom;
        final int[] to = mTo;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View v = view.findViewById(to[i]);
            if (v != null) {
                boolean bound = false;
                if (binder != null) {
                    bound = binder.setViewValue(v, cursor, from[i]);
                }

                if (!bound) {
                    String text = cursor.getString(from[i]);
                    if (text == null) {
                        text = "";
                    }

                    if (v instanceof TextView) {
                        setViewText((TextView) v, text);
                    } else if (v instanceof ImageView) {
                        setViewImage((ImageView) v, text);
                    } else {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(v.getClass().getName() + " is not a " +
                                " view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the {@link ViewBinder} used to bind data to views.
     *
     * @return a ViewBinder or null if the binder does not exist
     *
     * @see #bindView(android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor)
     * @see #setViewBinder(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder)
     */
    public ViewBinder getViewBinder() {
        return mViewBinder;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the binder used to bind data to views.
     *
     * @param viewBinder the binder used to bind data to views, can be null to
     *        remove the existing binder
     *
     * @see #bindView(android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor)
     * @see #getViewBinder()
     */
    public void setViewBinder(ViewBinder viewBinder) {
        mViewBinder = viewBinder;
    }

    /**
     * Called by bindView() to set the image for an ImageView but only if
     * there is no existing ViewBinder or if the existing ViewBinder cannot
     * handle binding to an ImageView.
     *
     * By default, the value will be treated as an image resource. If the
     * value cannot be used as an image resource, the value is used as an
     * image Uri.
     *
     * Intended to be overridden by Adapters that need to filter strings
     * retrieved from the database.
     *
     * @param v ImageView to receive an image
     * @param value the value retrieved from the cursor
     */
    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
        try {
            v.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(value));
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            v.setImageURI(Uri.parse(value));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called by bindView() to set the text for a TextView but only if
     * there is no existing ViewBinder or if the existing ViewBinder cannot
     * handle binding to a TextView.
     *
     * Intended to be overridden by Adapters that need to filter strings
     * retrieved from the database.
     * 
     * @param v TextView to receive text
     * @param text the text to be set for the TextView
     */    
    public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {
        v.setText(text);
    }

    /**
     * Return the index of the column used to get a String representation
     * of the Cursor.
     *
     * @return a valid index in the current Cursor or -1
     *
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#convertToString(android.database.Cursor)
     * @see #setStringConversionColumn(int) 
     * @see #setCursorToStringConverter(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter)
     * @see #getCursorToStringConverter()
     */
    public int getStringConversionColumn() {
        return mStringConversionColumn;
    }

    /**
     * Defines the index of the column in the Cursor used to get a String
     * representation of that Cursor. The column is used to convert the
     * Cursor to a String only when the current CursorToStringConverter
     * is null.
     *
     * @param stringConversionColumn a valid index in the current Cursor or -1 to use the default
     *        conversion mechanism
     *
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#convertToString(android.database.Cursor)
     * @see #getStringConversionColumn()
     * @see #setCursorToStringConverter(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter)
     * @see #getCursorToStringConverter()
     */
    public void setStringConversionColumn(int stringConversionColumn) {
        mStringConversionColumn = stringConversionColumn;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the converter used to convert the filtering Cursor
     * into a String.
     *
     * @return null if the converter does not exist or an instance of
     *         {@link android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter}
     *
     * @see #setCursorToStringConverter(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter)
     * @see #getStringConversionColumn()
     * @see #setStringConversionColumn(int)
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#convertToString(android.database.Cursor)
     */
    public CursorToStringConverter getCursorToStringConverter() {
        return mCursorToStringConverter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the converter  used to convert the filtering Cursor
     * into a String.
     *
     * @param cursorToStringConverter the Cursor to String converter, or
     *        null to remove the converter
     *
     * @see #setCursorToStringConverter(android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter) 
     * @see #getStringConversionColumn()
     * @see #setStringConversionColumn(int)
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#convertToString(android.database.Cursor)
     */
    public void setCursorToStringConverter(CursorToStringConverter cursorToStringConverter) {
        mCursorToStringConverter = cursorToStringConverter;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a CharSequence representation of the specified Cursor as defined
     * by the current CursorToStringConverter. If no CursorToStringConverter
     * has been set, the String conversion column is used instead. If the
     * conversion column is -1, the returned String is empty if the cursor
     * is null or Cursor.toString().
     *
     * @param cursor the Cursor to convert to a CharSequence
     *
     * @return a non-null CharSequence representing the cursor
     */
    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        if (mCursorToStringConverter != null) {
            return mCursorToStringConverter.convertToString(cursor);
        } else if (mStringConversionColumn > -1) {
            return cursor.getString(mStringConversionColumn);
        }

        return super.convertToString(cursor);
    }

    /**
     * Create a map from an array of strings to an array of column-id integers in cursor c.
     * If c is null, the array will be discarded.
     *
     * @param c the cursor to find the columns from
     * @param from the Strings naming the columns of interest
     */
    private void findColumns(Cursor c, String[] from) {
        if (c != null) {
            int i;
            int count = from.length;
            if (mFrom == null || mFrom.length != count) {
                mFrom = new int[count];
            }
            for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                mFrom[i] = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(from[i]);
            }
        } else {
            mFrom = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor c) {
        // super.swapCursor() will notify observers before we have
        // a valid mapping, make sure we have a mapping before this
        // happens
        findColumns(c, mOriginalFrom);
        return super.swapCursor(c);
    }

    /**
     * Change the cursor and change the column-to-view mappings at the same time.
     *  
     * @param c The database cursor.  Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param from A list of column names representing the data to bind to the UI.  Can be null 
     *            if the cursor is not available yet.
     * @param to The views that should display column in the "from" parameter.
     *            These should all be TextViews. The first N views in this list
     *            are given the values of the first N columns in the from
     *            parameter.  Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
     */
    public void changeCursorAndColumns(Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        mOriginalFrom = from;
        mTo = to;
        // super.changeCursor() will notify observers before we have
        // a valid mapping, make sure we have a mapping before this
        // happens
        findColumns(c, mOriginalFrom);
        super.changeCursor(c);
    }

    /**
     * This class can be used by external clients of SimpleCursorAdapter
     * to bind values fom the Cursor to views.
     *
     * You should use this class to bind values from the Cursor to views
     * that are not directly supported by SimpleCursorAdapter or to
     * change the way binding occurs for views supported by
     * SimpleCursorAdapter.
     *
     * @see SimpleCursorAdapter#bindView(android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor)
     * @see SimpleCursorAdapter#setViewImage(ImageView, String) 
     * @see SimpleCursorAdapter#setViewText(TextView, String)
     */
    public static interface ViewBinder {
        /**
         * Binds the Cursor column defined by the specified index to the specified view.
         *
         * When binding is handled by this ViewBinder, this method must return true.
         * If this method returns false, SimpleCursorAdapter will attempts to handle
         * the binding on its own.
         *
         * @param view the view to bind the data to
         * @param cursor the cursor to get the data from
         * @param columnIndex the column at which the data can be found in the cursor
         *
         * @return true if the data was bound to the view, false otherwise
         */
        boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex);
    }

    /**
     * This class can be used by external clients of SimpleCursorAdapter
     * to define how the Cursor should be converted to a String.
     *
     * @see android.widget.CursorAdapter#convertToString(android.database.Cursor)
     */
    public static interface CursorToStringConverter {
        /**
         * Returns a CharSequence representing the specified Cursor.
         *
         * @param cursor the cursor for which a CharSequence representation
         *        is requested
         *
         * @return a non-null CharSequence representing the cursor
         */
        CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor);
    }

}
```

Объясните почему?

Comment: Таких переменных не видно в базовых классах. Добавьте деталей в вопрос, покажите код. В данный момент вам ответить никак нельзя.

Comment: Юрий, а разве вы не ответили, сказав, что переменные не видны в базовых классах или нужно приложить фрагмент кода SimpleCursorAdapter-а?

Comment: Я имел в виду, что открыв в студии исходники адаптера таких переменных там не нашёл. Предположил, что они где-то у вас в коде. Так что да - показывайте свой код, где именно что-то не видно и что именно не видно)

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ну, в ява-доке к полям написано, что они должны быть приватными и скрытыми от SDK. Видимо как-то это таки сделали. Возможно, у вас устаревший код и сейчас используется более новая версия где поля эти уже приватные.

Comment: Подскажите тогда как переопределить bindiew() чтобы работа с массивами продолжала осуществляться на уровне исходников

Comment: Боюсь, что не знаю. С курсорами дела не имел. К тому же не ясно какая у вас задача. Зачем вам эти массивы, если они разработчиками адаптера задуманы приватными? Возможно, вы пытаетесь вашу задачу решить не самым оптимальным способом?

Comment: Хочу внести изменения в данный метод, чтобы немного откорректировать его работу с TextView (да, теперь пойду, конечно, другим путем), но любопытно как все таки решить данный вопрос. По науке как понимаю это решается наследованием с переопределением, а в данном случае, видимо, остается возможность только вызывать через super родительский метод в  переопределяемом и добавить свой функционал не трогая оригинал из-за закрытых полей, верно?

Comment: Да, вроде, всё верно) Вот пример, может, поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17709253/3212712

Comment: Да, очень похоже на верное решение. Только не могу проголосовать за ваш комментарий)

Comment: Вы можете опубликовать код из ссылки в виде ответа. Тогда ща него смогу я проголосовать)

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы с переопределением:

При расширении адаптера курсора необходимо переопределить методы bindView и newView. Метод bindView используется для привязки всех данных к данному виду, таких как установка текста в TextView. Метод newView используется для раздувания нового представления и возврата его, в этот момент вы не привязываете данные к виду. Большинство адаптеров используют функцию getView, но при расширении адаптера курсора вы должны использовать bindView и newView.

```
public class Custom_Adapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        private Context mContext;
        private Context appContext;
        private int layout;
        private Cursor cr;
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;

        public Custom_Adapter(Context context,int layout, Cursor c,String[] from,int[] to) {
            super(context,layout,c,from,to);
            this.layout=layout;
            this.mContext = context;
            this.inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.cr=c;
        }

        @Override
        public View newView (Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                return inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
            TextView titleS=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.TitleSong);
            TextView artistS=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Artist);

            int Title_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int Artist_index=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

            titleS.setText(cursor.getString(Title_index));
            artistS.setText(cursor.getString(Artist_index));

        }

}
```

Источник:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17709253/3212712